# System of linear n-th order Ivp

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone please help me in explaining this question?

> Write the linear $n$-th order IVP  $$x^{n} + a_{1}(t) x^{n-1} + \dots
> + a_{n}(t) x = b(t)$$ $$x(t_{0}) = x_{0}, \quad x'(t_{0}) = x_{1}, \quad \dots, \quad x^{n-1}(t_{0}) = x_{n-1}$$ as a system. Prove that
>   it admits a unique solution.

Comment: @Moo thanks a lot ....

Comment: @Moo what about uniqueness? Is there any idea ??

Comment: Are you sure the last term in your ODE before the equality is supposed to be $a_{n}(t) x$ and not just $a_{n}(t)$? The $x$ doesn't seem to fit the pattern. Also, have you written the problem as a system yet?